# Make categories on uitapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, categories, uitapgesturerecognizer

Is it possible to make category on `UITapGestureRecognizer`? I want to make convenience method to avoid (alloc-init) game.

I tired this:

```
+(void)tapDetector :(sel)selectormethod tags:(int)tag :tapsRequired:(int)taps{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:ac action:@selector(??????????????????:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = tag;
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = tag;   
}
```

But problem is that I cant get selectorMethod as a action parameter... Can anyone help in this regard?

Comment: "prob is that i cant get selectorMethod as a action paramter" Why can't you? A selector is an object that can be passed as a parameter, just like any other. What's the trouble? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector type is `SEL` (not sel), and you can pass it directly as the action (no "@selector..." stuff. Eg:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:ac action:selectormethod];
```

---

`@selector(...)` is a compiler directive that uses the compile-time symbol information to convert the string version of a selector into a constant `SEL` selector reference for use at runtime. In your case, the caller would be doing that work, and the resulting value can be then passed around.